# How to check frequency of every unique value from pandas data-frame?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

If I have a data-frame of 2000 and in which let say brand have 142 unique values and i want to count frequency of every unique value form 1 to 142.values should change dynamically.

```
brand=clothes_z.brand_name
brand.describe(include="all")
unique_brand=brand.unique()
brand.describe(include="all"),unique_brand
```

Output:

```
(count       2613
unique      142
 top       Mango
 freq         54
 Name: brand_name, dtype: object,
array(['Jack & Jones', 'TOM TAILOR DENIM', 'YOURTURN', 'Tommy Jeans',
        'Alessandro Zavetti', 'adidas Originals', 'Volcom', 'Pier One',
        'Superdry', 'G-Star', 'SIKSILK', 'Tommy Hilfiger', 'Karl Kani',
        'Alpha Industries', 'Farah', 'Nike Sportswear',
        'Calvin Klein Jeans', 'Champion', 'Hollister Co.', 'PULL&BEAR',
        'Nike Performance', 'Even&Odd', 'Stradivarius', 'Mango',
        'Champion Reverse Weave', 'Massimo Dutti', 'Selected Femme Petite',
        'NAF NAF', 'YAS', 'New Look', 'Missguided', 'Miss Selfridge',
        'Topshop', 'Miss Selfridge Petite', 'Guess', 'Esprit Collection',
        'Vero Moda', 'ONLY Petite', 'Selected Femme', 'ONLY', 'Dr.Denim',
        'Bershka', 'Vero Moda Petite', 'PULL & BEAR', 'New Look Petite',
        'JDY', 'Even & Odd', 'Vila', 'Lacoste', 'PS Paul Smith',
        'Redefined Rebel', 'Selected Homme', 'BOSS', 'Brave Soul', 'Mind',
        'Scotch & Soda', 'Only & Sons', 'The North Face',
        'Polo Ralph Lauren', 'Gym King', 'Selected Woman', 'Rich & Royal',
        'Rooms', 'Glamorous', 'Club L London', 'Zalando Essentials',
        'edc by Esprit', 'OYSHO', 'Oasis', 'Gina Tricot',
        'Glamorous Petite', 'Cortefiel', 'Missguided Petite',
        'Missguided Tall', 'River Island', 'INDICODE JEANS',
        'Kings Will Dream', 'Topman', 'Esprit', 'Diesel', 'Key Largo',
        'Mennace', 'Lee', "Levi's®", 'adidas Performance', 'jordan',
        'Jack & Jones PREMIUM', 'They', 'Springfield', 'Benetton', 'Fila',
        'Replay', 'Original Penguin', 'Kronstadt', 'Vans', 'Jordan',
        'Apart', 'New look', 'River island', 'Freequent', 'Mads Nørgaard',
        '4th & Reckless', 'Morgan', 'Honey punch', 'Anna Field Petite',
        'Noisy may', 'Pepe Jeans', 'Mavi', 'mint & berry', 'KIOMI', 'mbyM',
        'Escada Sport', 'Lost Ink', 'More & More', 'Coffee', 'GANT',
        'TWINTIP', 'MAMALICIOUS', 'Noisy May', 'Pieces', 'Rest',
        'Anna Field', 'Pinko', 'Forever New', 'ICHI', 'Seafolly', 'Object',
        'Freya', 'Wrangler', 'Cream', 'LTB', 'G-star', 'Dorothy Perkins',
        'Carhartt WIP', 'Betty & Co', 'GAP', 'ONLY Tall', 'Next', 'HUGO',
        'Violet by Mango', 'WEEKEND MaxMara', 'French Connection'],
       dtype=object))
```

As it is showing only frequency of Mango "54" because it is top frequency and I want every value frequency like what is the frequency of `Jack & Jones`, `TOM TAILOR DENIM` and `YOURTURN` and so on... and values should change dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do,

```
clothes_z.brand_name.value_counts()
```

This would list down the unique values and would give you the frequency of every element in that Pandas Series.

Comment: Yes ! dude this is also a simple way..can we convert this series to data-frame and draw visualization

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter


ll = [...your list of brands...]
c = Counter(ll)
# you can do whatever you want with your counted values
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient='index', columns=['counted'])
```

Comment: it returns the collections.Counter and how I can convert it into table of data-frame

Comment: just find out how to do counter -> dataframe. it is worth to note collections is powerful module in python worth knowing. please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks man you make my life easy..! how i can give you credit..?